# css - parent :before pseudoelement with child alt attribute as content

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

A series of `ul` elements contained within separate `div` elements need to not only have the correct content in their `:before` pseudo element, but also keep the bold tag titles adjacent to the lists.

Additionally, when there are no lists present within the `div` in question, nothing should appear whatsoever. This is why I'm looking for CSS as a solution, because if I hard-code the titles within the `div` it will appear if there are no lists present.

I cannot predict which instances of this unique `div` will have a `ul` within ahead of time - our application generates content based on user input from drop-down menus, and so if a menu is never used, a `ul` is not created.

I am unable to use JavaScript of any sort for this labeling process.

This is what I would *like* to see:

*Foo Items*

**List One**

- aaaa
- bbbbb
- cccc

**List Two**

- defdefdef
- ghighighi

*Bar Items*

**List One**

- xxx
- yyy

**List Two**

- zzzzzzz
- aaaabbbbccc

At present I am trying to use the `alt` attribute of the `ul` to populate the `div:before` area. This is with the hope that there is a way to define CSS which says "for each `div` that contains an `.exam` class element, place the `ul`'s `attr(alt)` in the `div:before` element".

This is what I've tried:

```
<div>
    <b>Far</b>
    <ul class="exam" alt="Foo Items">
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>Things</li>
    </ul>
    <b>Near</b>
    <ul class="exam" alt="Foo Items">
        <li>dunno</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <b>Far</b>
    <ul class="exam" alt="Bar Items">
        <li>Foo</li>
    </ul>
    <b>Near</b>
    <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>eggs</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS to go with it:

```
div > .exam:first-of-type:before {
    content:attr(alt);
    font-style:italic;
}
ul {
    margin:0 0 1em 1em;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    margin-left:2em;
}
```

Please see the jsfiddle link here - https://jsfiddle.net/f6gwyvuu/

**I realize it's all a bit convoluted but unfortunately this is the result of working around the way in which the application generates its content. I don't really have control over that, I can only stylized the elements it creates.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds as though you are trying to **misuse** the `content` property to add actual content.

Comment: I think that can not be done with CSS only.

Comment: Indeed...this is the sort of thing that cries out for a JS solution

Comment: Do you want something like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/f6gwyvuu/1/)

Comment: You need to use JS...or better, PHP for this.

Comment: It may well be a misuse, but I am unable to add JS and do it naturally. Not because I do not know JS but because I'm expressly forbidden from adding it to the output of the application. It just isn't up to me

Comment: "for each div that contains an .exam class element, place the ul's attr(alt) in the div:before element" This isn't possible because attr() can only take attributes from the same element that you define the :before pseudo-element in. For example a div:before can only take attributes from its own div, and a ul:before can only take attributes from its own ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `ul` elements can't have an `alt` attribute. You can use custom `data-*` attributes instead.

And it doesn't make much sense to repeat the same data in each `ul`. Instead, add it only to the `div`.

Then, you can use

```css
div:not(:empty):before {
  content: attr(data-alt);
  display: block;
}
```

```css
div:not(:empty):before {
  content: attr(data-alt);
  display: block;
  font-style: italic;
}
ul {
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div data-alt="Foo Items">
  <b>Far</b>
  <ul class="exam">
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Things</li>
  </ul>
  <b>Near</b>
  <ul class="exam">
    <li>dunno</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-alt="Baz Items"></div>
<div data-alt="Bar Items">
  <b>Far</b>
  <ul class="exam">
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
  <b>Near</b>
  <ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>eggs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably as close as I'll get to an answer - I know it seems weird the way I went about it, and that's just because a lot of the data that this application places on its text output is locked down so I can't always just do the most sensible thing. Still, the `:empty` selector is one I didn't know about and it's totally relevant here, so I'll start with this and see where it leads me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) and [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) css selectors.

You can do something like this:

```
div > .exam:not(:empty):before {
    content:attr(alt);
    font-style:italic;
}
ul {
    margin:0 0 1em 1em;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    margin-left:2em;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/f6gwyvuu/3/)

If you are trying to change styles of previous sibling, then it is not possible using css. You better add another attribute as you did by adding `alt` attribute. And also it is best practice to add our custom attributes with a prefix as `data-`.

Comment: Why is your :empty in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, try

```
div {position:relative;} /*let this be the absolute container*/
div > .exam {position: static;}
div:not(:empty) {padding-top: 30px;} /*for div with generated content, only works for short titles*/
div > .exam:first-of-type:before {
    content:attr(alt);
    font-style:italic;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -1em; /*compensate your ul margin*/
}
ul {
    margin:0 0 1em 1em;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    margin-left:2em;
}
```

This works for short titles, but maybe tweak it to work for long titles as well.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luongatoolz/f6gwyvuu/2/)